# How to deploy 2 applications(same ear) to a single jboss on different ports. Is it even possible?

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I use Jboss eap 6.4. 
I'd like to have those ears deployed simultaneously but on different ports. 
If I just put 2 ears into deployments I got: DuplicateServiceException: Service /app already registered.

Comment: You could try creating server-groups with offset and then deploying it different servers with the same jboss-eap instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure JBoss for App1.war on port 8080 and App2.war on port 8543, you should implement the following steps:

- First of all, you have to add socket-binding for 8543 (as port 8080 is already defined).

`<socket-binding name="http2" port="8543"/>`

- In web subsystem the following **connectors** should be declared:

`<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" />`

`<connector name="http2" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http2" />`

- Additionally, in web subsystem the following two **virtual-servers** should be declared:

`<virtual-server name="host1" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="App1.war">
       <alias name="first.com"/>
 </virtual-server>`

`<virtual-server name="host2" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="App2.war">
       <alias name="second.com"/>
 </virtual-server>`

- Associate the appropriate virtual-server with the respective connector:

`<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http">
        <virtual-server name="host1"/>
</connector>`

`<connector name="http2" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http2">
        <virtual-server name="host2"/>
</connector>`

- The final step is to configure each application with the right **jboss-web.xml** in WEB-INF:

`- For App1.war
 <jboss-web>
        <virtual-host>host1</virtual-host>
 </jboss-web>`

`- For App2.war
 <jboss-web>
        <virtual-host>host2</virtual-host>
 </jboss-web>`

Now each application can be accessed by following the urls:

For App1.war - http://first.com:8080/App1/index.jsp

For App2.war - http://second.com:8543/App2/index.jsp

Please bear in mind that in `/etc/hosts` of the system, you must add the corresponding virtual-server alias names:

`127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost first.com second.com`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Panagiotis , it works. I just also wandering is it possible to have common alias like localhost and differentiate only via ports like:

For App1.war - http://localhost:8080/App1/index.jsp

For App2.war - http://localhost.com:8543/App2/index.jsp